# PowerShell failed to initialize while creating a ASP.net project in VS 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

So, was trying to make a software in ASP.net, using Visual Studio 2015 in C#.
The problem I am having is that after I create the project I get an error message.

this: "failed to initialize the PowerShell host. if your PowerShell execution setting is set to AllSinged, open Package Manager Console to initialize the host first." I've been unable to fix this so far. any suggestion?

Comment: Have you updated the setting for 32 bit PowerShell?

Comment: I got win 64. but I guess I did it. yet, I am getting no result

Comment: There are two versions of PowerShell installed on win64; an x64 version which runs by default and an x86 version. When you run powershell from windows, you run the x64 version. Visual Studio uses the x86 version. You have to make sure to do the work to fix this problem in the x86 version.

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for the solution. but I fixed it. thank you for taking time and trying to support me.

Answer (score 0):

go to run (Win +R) type 'regedit' it will open popup to edit system properties.
Go to below path ,
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell**

Right click "Execution policy" and click modify. If it has value as **"AllSinged"**  just remove that and save.
now you try creating your new project. this is how my issue got resolved.